# jQuery each function return always first option

Tags: jquery, html-select, each

I try to browse a select with jQuery and using each function but my alert in my each me back X times (where x is the number of option) the value of my first option ..

An idea?

```
$("#selectionChamp option").each(function(){            
        alert($("#selectionChamp option").val());
    });
```

Comment: please wait until this is possible

Comment: Some of your questions are several weeks old. You can accept an answer after 5 mins of asking a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (and really all of the jQuery getters) returns the requested value for the first element in the matched set. Within the context of [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), to access the element currently being evaluated use `this`:

```
$("#selectionChamp option").each(function(){            
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and bonus question : If i want to hide an option ? $(this).hide() doesn't work...

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Select options are not *hideable*. You would have to remove the element

Comment: @ClémentAndraud ^like @Phil said, I don't think you can hide them per se. It's possible to disable them using `$(this).prop("disabled",true)`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectionChamp option").each(function(){            
    console.log(this.value);
});
```